# Writing data into table with unknown number of rows

Tags: javascript

I am in a very basic "Intro to JS" course and my solving of this problem needs to equally basic and antiquated.

The exercise is supposed to display a table with a header with student names & scores of those scoring 90 or more. (Data is drawn from another js file.)

It then is supposed to display the total number of students and the total number of students scoring 90 or more. My math & if statement seem to be working, but the display is not...by a long shot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const ZERO = 0;
const NINETY_PERCENT = 90;

var studentName;
var studentScore;
var totalStudents;
var totalStudentsWithAs;
var studentRecords;

studentRecords = openStudentExamRecords();

function initializeExamRecords() {
    totalStudents = ZERO;
    totalStudentsWithAs = ZERO;
}

function startTable() {
    document.write("<th>Student Name</th>");
    document.write("<th>Exam Score</th>");
}

function printRecords() {
    initializeExamRecords();
    startTable();
    while (studentRecords.readNextRecord()) {
        studentName = studentRecords.getStudentName();
        studentScore = studentRecords.getStudentScore();
        totalStudents++;

        if (studentScore >= NINETY_PERCENT) {
            document.write("</td><td>");
            document.write(studentName);
            document.write("</td><td>");
            document.write(studentScore);
            totalStudentsWithAs++;
            totalStudents = Number(totalStudents);
            totalStudentsWithAs = Number(totalStudentsWithAs); alert("");
        }
    }
}

function endTable() {
    document.write("</td></tr>");
}

function printTotals() {
    printRecords();
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write("<tr><td colspan='5'>&nbsp;</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td colspan='5'>Total Students: <strong>" +
        totalStudents + "</strong></td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td colspan='5'>Total Sudents with A's: <strong>" +
        totalStudentsWithAs + "</strong></td></tr>");
    document.write("</td><tr>");
}

function endTable() {
    document.write("</td></tr>");
}

printTotals();
endTable();
```

Comment: Why oh why do JavaScript instructors continue to teach students `document.write()`?!

Comment: You have two identical functions called `endTable`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Because doing anything else would require them to teach students the DOM, which is probably a recipe for disaster in beginner's classes.

Comment: Thanx so much. endTable() was supposed to simply stop rows from being added to the table after all students' names & scores over 90% were posted. Still not sure how to do that. Instrux: This function will output an HTML table end tag.

Comment: @Tomalak I have been an IT trainer for 20 years. Teaching DOM basics in an intro. class is not a big deal. Getting into the full DOM API is reserved for later.

Comment: Yes, I have heard from many how antiquated what we're learning is...jsfiddle won't even accept document.write!

Comment: If you are just introducing the basic concepts of loops and if statements, having to make a detour through DOM and objects and so on can take more time than you have. Plus, it's on the learning materials that you've been copying all those years. ;)

Comment: So can anyone help me out? This was the example of how to build the body of the table...                                                                                                                                      document.write("<tr><td class=\"righttd\">");
document.write(customerNumber);
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(customerName);
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(address);
document.write("</td><td class=\"righttd\">");
document.write(gasUsage);
document.write("</td><td class=\"righttd\">");
document.write(amountOwed);
document.write("</td></tr>");